# How to download vsix files extensions correctly into VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, vsix

After installing Visual Studio 2015 enterprise update 1 (I was using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate) I want to install the colored console extension I was using in vs 2013 in 2015 as well. When running the vsixInstaller.exe i get the following exception:
`the extension is already installed to all applicable products`
although it is not installed in my vs 2015.

I can't download it from the visual studio itself because this machine works in an isolated network

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extension is available for VS 2015, and ask a friend to download it for you

Comment: It is available in VS 2015, and how can a friend install it for me? The only way I knew of was to get the vsix file

Comment: A friend could download it for you and pass the vsxi on to you!